# some environment variables not load under certain circumstances

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, linux-mint

It is most weird. I have set the environment variable TEST in  .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile,   /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/ - everywhere a sane computer might look for it:

```
    TEST=successfull
    export TEST
```

And when I open a terminal window, typing "echo $TEST" or "env" gives me the value of this variable nicely.

However, when I doubleclick an .desktop-file, the environment variable does not exist. And, strangely, when I fire up geany with a simple file containing

```
    #!/bin/bash  
    env
    echo $TEST
```

, and execute it by pressing F5, it opens up a terminal window - and it won't show the value of TEST. If I start this same file from any terminal window - the environment variable is there as expected!!

This bothers me since its illogical and it blocks steam from running - steam requires the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I put in "steam" in terminal - all loads fine. But if I doubleclick any steam icon - which does nothing more than execute "steam" with some parameters - nothing happens - because it cannot find its LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I run Linux Mint LMDE with all updates installed. The same problem occurs wheter "gnome-terminal" or "mate-terminal" acts as gui frontend.

Can you reproduce? If yes, where is the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/etc/environment` for now and restart your LMDE session. Gnome sources the environment from `~/.gnomerc` or something, and I imagine LMDE has an equivalent too, but for now `/etc/environment` should work for you.

Comment: Hi, ~/.gnomerc does not exist, however, this solution worked! At least for every variable that is not LD_LIBRARY_PATH - this one seems to be blocked.